# Plotting a better treemap using ggplot and the geom_rect hack, but how to get the labels correct?

Tags: r, ggplot2, treemap

I have found it challenging to create a treemap using ggplot, and [this blog example](https://yjunechoe.github.io/posts/2020-06-30-treemap-with-ggplot/) captured the issues very well and also provided a nice work around.  The work around takes the output from the tree map package to create a ggplot version with geom_rect.

My problem and question is how to adjust the labels and, if I wanted to, colors by hierarchy as I have more groups than the linked example and have different labeling requirements.

**Here is a reproducible simple example:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(treemap)


# Create dummy data
tree_data <- data.frame(
  my_segment = c(
    rep("seg_a", 5),
    rep("seg_b", 6),
    rep("seg_c", 7)),
  my_class = c(
    rep("class_1", 2),
    rep("class_2", 2),
    rep("class_3", 1),
    rep("class_4", 2),
    rep("class_5", 2),
    rep("class_6", 2),
    rep("class_7", 1),
    rep("class_8", 3),
    rep("class_9", 3)),
  my_type = c(
    rep("type_1", 7),
    rep("type_2", 6),
    rep("type_3", 5)),
  vals = round(runif(18, min = 20, max = 100), 0)
)
```

Here is the head of the sample dataframe:

```
   my_segment my_class my_type vals
1       seg_a  class_1  type_1   86
2       seg_a  class_1  type_1   41
3       seg_a  class_2  type_1   23
4       seg_a  class_2  type_1   79
5       seg_a  class_3  type_1   33
6       seg_b  class_4  type_1   82
7       seg_b  class_4  type_1   85
8       seg_b  class_5  type_2   40
9       seg_b  class_5  type_2   83
10      seg_b  class_6  type_2   69
11      seg_b  class_6  type_2   98
12      seg_c  class_7  type_2   91
13      seg_c  class_8  type_2   33
```

The tree map package runs fine, but produces unreadable output in RStudio, and I'd like to be able to customize more with ggplot (similar to the linked article)

```
# Run treemap function
tree_p <- treemap(
  tree_data,
  index            = c("my_segment", "my_class", "my_type"),
  vColor           = "my_segment",
  vSize            = "vals",
  type             = "index",
  fontsize.labels  = c(15, 12, 10),
  fontcolor.labels = c("white", "orange", "green"),
  fontface.labels  = c(2, 1, 1),
  bg.labels        = 0,
  align.labels     = list(
    c("center", "center"),
    c("right", "bottom"),
    c("left", "bottom")
  ),
  overlap.labels   = 0.5,
  inflate.labels   = FALSE
)
    
# Note:  unreadable output in Rstudio (too small)
```

[image: treemap_output]

Using the workaround in this blog, but adding an additional hierarchy and wanted to change the labeling is where the problem comes in.

```
# Create the plot in ggplot using geom_rect

# Get underlying data created from running treemap
tm_plot_data <- tree_p$tm %>% 
  mutate(x1 = x0 + w,
         y1 = y0 + h) %>% 
  mutate(x = (x0+x1)/2,
         y = (y0+y1)/2) %>% 
  mutate(
    primary_group = case_when(
      level == 1 ~ 1.5,
      level == 2 ~ 0.75,
      TRUE       ~ 0.5
    )
  ) 



# Plot
ggplot(tm_plot_data, aes(xmin = x0, ymin = y0, xmax = x1, ymax = y1)) + 
  # add fill and borders for groups and subgroups
  geom_rect(aes(fill = color, size = primary_group),
            show.legend = FALSE,
            color       = "black",
            alpha       = 0.3
  ) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  # set thicker lines for group borders
  scale_size(range = range(tm_plot_data$primary_group)) +
  # add labels
  ggfittext::geom_fit_text(aes(label = my_segment), color = "white", min.size = 1) +
  ggfittext::geom_fit_text(aes(label = my_class), color = "blue", min.size = 1) +
  ggfittext::geom_fit_text(aes(label = my_type), color = "red", min.size = 1) +
  # options
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_void()
```

[image: treemap_hack]

**So the question I have is there a way to create the labeling like treemap?  Specifically, `seg_a`, `seg_b`, and `seg_c` should only appear once, centered over the area of their respective segments.  I'd also like to move the labels so that they do not overlap**

Thanks for any help and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you use your full dataset `tm_plot_data` to add the labels. Hence, for each upper level you you get multiple labels. To solve this issue aggregate your datasets and pass these datasets as `data` to `ggfittext::geom_fit_text`. To deal with overlapping labels you could e.g. use the `place` argument of `ggfittext::geom_fit_text` to move the class labels to the bottom left and the type labels to the topright.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(treemap)

set.seed(123)

tm_seg <- tm_plot_data %>% 
  group_by(my_segment) %>% 
  summarise(x0 = min(x0), y0 = min(y0), y1 = max(y1), x1 = max(x1)) %>% 
  ungroup()

tm_class <- tm_plot_data %>% 
  group_by(my_segment, my_class) %>% 
  summarise(x0 = min(x0), y0 = min(y0), y1 = max(y1), x1 = max(x1)) %>% 
  ungroup()

tm_type <- tm_plot_data %>% 
  group_by(my_segment, my_class, my_type) %>% 
  summarise(x0 = min(x0), y0 = min(y0), y1 = max(y1), x1 = max(x1)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# Plot
ggplot(tm_plot_data, aes(xmin = x0, ymin = y0, xmax = x1, ymax = y1)) +
  # add fill and borders for groups and subgroups
  geom_rect(aes(fill = color, size = primary_group),
    show.legend = FALSE,
    color       = "black",
    alpha       = 0.3
  ) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  # set thicker lines for group borders
  scale_size(range = range(tm_plot_data$primary_group)) +
  # add labels
  ggfittext::geom_fit_text(data = tm_seg, aes(label = my_segment), color = "white", min.size = 4) +
  ggfittext::geom_fit_text(data = tm_class, aes(label = my_class), color = "blue", min.size = 1, place = "bottomleft") +
  ggfittext::geom_fit_text(data = tm_type, aes(label = my_type), color = "red", min.size = 1, place = "topright") +
  # options
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_void()
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_fit_text).
#> Warning: Removed 12 rows containing missing values (geom_fit_text).
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  I wasn't sure how to make that work.